# Is Java Memory Consumption a good Web Application Healthcheck Metric?

Tags: java, servlets, garbage-collection, metrics, health-monitoring

I have implemented a healthcheck servlet on our jetty 8 server using [Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/). Besides being polled from our Load Balancer the Metrics are periodically (5min) written to log files. Additionally email-notifications are sent, when some of the metrics such as CPU Load or Memory Consumption reach critical limits.

This works perfect for CPU Load an System Memory Consumption. However, one of the metrics defined to measure the JVM Memory Consumption regularly exceeds the defined threshold of 95%, although the server is running stable. So we might have to re-think our decision about this particular metric. Is it a good metric to use in a healthcheck? Is it an indication of a memory leak that our web application regularly hits threshold until the Garbage Collector is run or is that normal behavior that is to be expected for every long running web application?

Thank you for your input.

Here is our Code, that impelments the JVM Memory Healthcheck.

**Java Runtime Memory**

```
    private final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Result check() throws Exception {

        final long freeMem = this.runtime.freeMemory();
        // maxMemory() is the value set by the JVM -Xmx (Max HeapSize) parameter
        final long maxMem = this.runtime.maxMemory();
        final long usedMem = maxMem - freeMem;          

        final double value = RatioGauge.Ratio.of(usedMem, maxMem).getValue();
        final double threshold = 0.95;

        if (value < threshold) {
            // Everything OK: Memory usage usage is below the threshold.
        } else {
            // NOT OK: Memory usage is above the threshold.
        }
    }
```

Comment: The fix is in the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish baseline. As long as your app works fine under desired load (number of request/sec, num of online users, etc), any cpu/memory consumption will do, more or less. Once you have baseline, you can add features to your code and then check if features make consumption decrease or increase and act accordingly. Then, if needed, you will optimize places in code which worsened after features were added (or you discover that no local code change saves you, and you need more hw to support new features under given load, or you need to re-design some components of your app, but it's another story).

So, it's not an absolute value that matter most (although having JVM heap consumption constantly at 95% *is* a bit worrying), but a change between code changes.

Comment: We perform the before/after memory checks you suggest during development time using Java Profilers (integrated in Netbeans or Eclipse). The problem at hand is slightly different as we need to check health at production time. In the past week, we have run several tests trying to establish a threshold/baseline for JVM Memory Consumption. Increasing the threshold up to 99% still triggers warnings every now and then - just before the GC is run. To avoid the problem of occasional peaks we calculate a sliding average over the past 5 mins. Still, using this metric doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Could it be you simply need to increase JVM Heap (_-Xmx_)? Nothing so far positively indicated you have memory leak, only that your app consume almost all available heap...

Comment: Maybe - I will test it and report back.

Comment: We have increased the JVM Heap Size and the server has run stable for more than a week now. Thank you for your help in resolving this issue!